# Foundation interchange will not display images

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am new to Zurb-foundation and want to implement interchange. I have followed the installation process to the letter but the images will not load, am I missing something. I have stripped my code of everything but interchange so that you can see how I have tried to use it. I have checked and double checked all of the script and image links and they are all correct, so why wont it work?

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foundation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foundation.interchange.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img data-interchange="[images/slider-image-one-small.jpg, (default)], [images/slider-image-one.jpg, (large)]">
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all the scripts at the bottom of the page rather than in the `<head>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <img data-interchange="[images/slider-image-one-small.jpg, (default)], [images/slider-image-one.jpg, (large)]">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foundation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foundation.interchange.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, thanks for the suggestion Gavin but that hasn't solved the problem. I'm back on this project now so I will let you know how I resolve the issue (if I resolve the issue!)

Comment: I just noticed the image path. It is 'images'? This means that your images folder needs to be in the root directory. It could possibly by 'assets' if you have uploaded them via the cms or 'themes/$ThemeDir/images' if the images folder is within your theme folder.